# how do I setup my D-link DSR250n to use openvpn server

Tags: openvpn, subnet, broadcast

My aim is to make my Iphone connect remotely (and securely) to my home network and get from the DHCP (the d-link router) IP on the same subnet.
This is because I have an client app that broadcasts on the subnet it's on to connect to it's server (which is on my home subnet).

So I've setup the D-Link DSR 250N to enable both IPSEC VPN and PPTP VPN. I can connect to my home network remotely and ping or ssh the servers in it. However the client app can't reach it's server (from running tcpdump inside the network with the client in it as well I can see it broadcast so I'm guessing this is the problem). Of course in IPSEC and PPTP the Iphone gets an IP on another subnet.

So how do I configure the openVPN server embedded in the D-Link to supply DHCP addresses to outside connections?

Comment: Please read our FAQ.  Or site description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that reinstalling the iPhone app solved my problem.